# How to run Android emulator remotely

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a android application that connects/send/receive to/from a server as part of its operation.

my final goal is to run this application on a number of android emulators on a remote machine(to save some computing resources on my laptop).

I SSHed to the remote machine and created the emulators remotely using `android create avd -n AVD_xxx -t 1` .

I tried to run the emulators using `emulator-arm -avd AVD_1` but it gave error that looks obvious : `SDL init failure, reason is: No available video device`
(if I run the command one the michine directly, it will run just fine)

I will appreciate if you help me solve this issue.

Note:
I don't need video provisions. is it possible to disable that by configuring AVD? this is just an example. you might have better solutions.

Comment: @flx hi, I am sure it will work. Just something else got in the way yesterday that I will solve it before I finally use your solution. I think the second option is what I am looking for. I will get back to you on this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. `export $DISPLAY` and show the emulator on some X display (tunneled or remotely existing)
2. run `emulator -no-window [-no-audio]` to start it without the need of a X display